# Node +Express dynamic routing

Tags: node.js, express, software-design

Iam creating a multitenet app ie, My clients have their own set of users.

It's a school app.
 IAM using same database for all schools for easy maintaience.

My routes will be like this

/API/some school code/users

/API/some other school code/users

/API/some other school code/users

My problem is that, here the school code is dynamic or user specific. Which I need to use filter the data from database.

So my each endpoint should be in the form of 
 /API/:schoolcode/users
  And get school code via req.params.schoolcode

Here is the problem is that I need to add :schoolcode in each beginning Route.
Or any middleware approach

Is there any alternative way. Better solutions please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could fragment your code and calling your routes handlers in you main node file

```
app.use('/api/:schoolcode([0-9]+)', schoolRouter)
```

I add some regex which allows to veriify that your path is only numerical but you can change in whatever you need.
And your schoolRouter could be like this:

```
 app.route('/users')
   .get((req, res) => {/** do something
 **/})
   .post((req, res) => { /* do something */})
```

Comment: IAM looking to create a config file which contains mapping of the numericid ->schoolcode. And find school code from route parameter and find corresponding school code (numeric) which is same as in the database too.how this approach

Comment: How can I get school code in School outer file: ie, in app.get()

Comment: You will find it in the request like you mentionned: req.params.schoolcode

Comment: Ok..now I understand.. could you pls look above comment

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand very well what are you trying to do. If I understand correctly you want to use the schooldcode (that you will get in the req.params) to retrieve informations from the database? If so, you could call your database where I put my /** do something **/ comment. I cannot help you more without knowing your db or config.

Comment: Say I have school code as /hfgcghs for more readability. But in my database I add 2001 or some integer value for faster response of the query. So I need to map this. So I would create a new config file and make a map. Hope you get me